# Execute function on clicking any element in a page except for two elements (in jQuery Mobile, jQM)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Execute a function on clicking any element in a page (with id='home_page') except for two elements (id='link1', id='link2'). These two elements have different function to execute on click.

The below are the two jQuery codes I've tried unsuccessfully. 
Code1:

```
$( document ).on("pageinit", '#home_page', function () { 
    $('#home_page').not('#link1, #link2').click(function(){
       alert();
    });
});
```

Code2:

```
$( document ).on("pageinit", '#home_page', function () { 
    $('#home_page:not(#link1, #link2)').click(function(){
       alert();
    });
});
```

The below is the jQM code for the page:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home_page">

    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" ><!-- Header -->
        <a id='link1' href="/done" rel="external">Home</a>
        <a id='link2' href="/exit" rel="external">Exit</a>
    </div><!-- Header -->

    <div data-role="content">
        <p>Home Page</p>
        <!-- Other elements -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you want to execute function when `<a>` Anchor is clicked? but not the ones in head (link1 and link2).

Comment: anyway, you should do it like this `$("a:not(#link1, #link2)").on("click", function () {` as `click` event will bubble up on the whole page if you bind it on `$("#homepage")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `.on()` method for binding events and as suggested in other answer you have a missing closing tag `});` for `click` event:

```
$( document ).on("pageinit", '#home_page', function () { 
   $('#home_page').not('#link1, #link2').on('click touchstart', function(){
      alert(); //---try adding "touchstart"--------^^^^^^^^^^
   });
});
```

and make sure that you have stopped the event to bubble up on `'#link1, #link2'` links with `event.stopPropagation();` only if you have bound some js events to these links.

---

As per your comments i just came with this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#home_page').not('#link1, #link2').click(function () {
        alert('page clicked');
    });

    $('#link1, #link2').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation(); //<---stops the event to bubble up
    });
});
```

What i noticed you have mentioned the href for your anchor tag to `http://www.google.com/`, what seems to me that navigating to google is not working in the fiddle while other link is working properly.

---

Try to change the first link href to this:

```
    <a id='link1' href="http://www.apple.com/mac/" rel="external">link1</a>
    <a id='link2' href="http://www.apple.com/" rel="external">link2</a>
```

---

#### [Demo @ Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/37Lp8/2/)

Comment: `event.stopPropagation` is used to stop the event to bubble up it does not prevent the default behavior, for that jQuery provides `event.preventDefault();` and i suggested to use if you have js applied to those links.

Comment: by using event.stopPropogation() on `'#link1, #link2'`, these links no longer work, I believe the click event is disabled on them ? can I have click event enabled on them so that they ONLY perform their natural function i.e going to a new page.

Comment: its okay but why you used `event.stopPropagation();`?

Comment: my mistake, please take a look at this updated code in the below JS FIDDLE link, unfortunately alert also works when the links are clicked. I would like the links to perform their natural function i.e going to a new page.  [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Falcon9/37Lp8/1/)

Comment: Thankyou very much, it works for links. I am now trying to apply the same for a popup for which it doesn't, would appreciate your help on this. Please take a look at this [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Falcon9/97dyW/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Seem like you're missing closing `})` for your `click` function:

```
$( document ).on("pageinit", '#home_page', function () { 
    $('#home_page').not('#link1, #link2').click(function(){
       alert();
    }); // <-- Here
});
```